How do I write a Cross Platform Asyncronous Socket Server in RAD Studio using TSocket libraries from System.Net.Socket?
Introduction
Generally the documentation in RAD Studio is very clear and has good examples for almost every scenario, in this case I was at a loss, the documentation has the following to say about TSocket:

To use your socket as a server socket:

Bind your socket to a local adapter.
Configure your socket to start
listening for incoming connections.
Accept an incoming connection.
Exchange data with the remote socket:  Receive data from the remote socket.
Send data to the remote socket.
Close your socket.


Now this is all very well but how do you actually do it and how do you use the methods and tie them together. I was able to get a single connection to work by following documentation from Microsoft MSDN.
Single Connection Solution
Here is my first solution I got "working":
program SocketServer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Net.Socket, System.Types;

var Socket: TSocket;

begin
  WriteLn('Starting Socket');
  Socket := TSocket.Create(TSocketType.TCP);
  Socket.Listen('127.0.0.1', '', 9006); //Very important ... second param is service

  try
    try
      var Connection := Socket.Accept(); //Waits until you connect - seems to be blocking

      while True do //All the examples have this
      begin
        WriteLn('Listening for data');
        var Bytes := Connection.Receive(); //Many ways to do this, opted for the simplest
        if StringOf(Bytes) <> '' then //Probably could have made this more optimal but it works
        begin
          WriteLn('Received: ' +StringOf(Bytes));
          WriteLn('Sent: OK');
          Connection.Send('OK');
        end;
        Sleep(1000); //Added this to give the processor a break
      end;
    finally
      Socket.Free;
    end;
  except
    On E:Exception do
    begin
      WriteLn('Exception happened:'+E.Message);
    end;
  end;

end.

The application works fine if you want to handle messages from a single connection. I was testing by using telnet, if I connect multiple times it doesn't seem to work:
telnet localhost 9006
If I typed in a bunch of characters and pressed enter I'd get a response.  How is this supposed to work Asyncronously, or how do I get it working in an asyncronous manner so I can accept more than one connection.  At this stage any rudimentary solution / point in the right direction will be great and I can refine from there. I'm also not clear when the connection should close or how to do it without causing an access violation or memory leak. I need to "exit" the main loop as well, not a big fan of endless loops ...
Before you answer this question

I'm not looking for "Use Indy components" as the solution, I already have this working with Indy but it's not very "Cross Platform" when it comes to the libraries needed to support it.
I'm not looking for links to 3rd party solutions who have made components out of this, sure I can spend $100-$300 dollars for an instant solution but the code is already in RAD Studio so it should be easy to use?

Thank you in advance for any clear solutions to this.  If I figure this out I will answer the question myself and welcome comments on how to make it better.

I'm curious whatever you build, if it will be resilient when run in a multi-platform context. The assumption is that Embarcadero did their due diligence and this built in networking code is identical in behaviour on all platforms. Given how different Winsock (windows), and Android, and iOS sockets are under the hood,  I wonder if they really succeeded.  We shall see. I'm one of the people who pays someone else (a third party) to handle this and test it because I have never trusted Embarcadero to get this right.

@WarrenP So am I!!! Hold thumbs on this as I will publish this in an open source library for everyone to use.

The TSocket.Accept() method is indeed blocking, it waits until a new client is accepted, unless you provide a Timeout for it. In this mode, you would have to service the client TSocket in a separate thread so the Accept() loop can go back to waiting for the next client (this is the same model that Indy's TIdTCPServer operates in internally).
For what you are looking for, use the TSocket.BeginAccept() method instead, which operates asynchronously.  You can provide it with a callback that will be notified when a new client has been accepted, or you can be given an IAsyncResult that you can poll periodically.  Either way, when the accept operation is finished, call the TSocket.EndAccept() method to get the accepted client TSocket.  You can then use the TSocket.BeginReceive() and TSocket.BeginSend() methods (and corresponding TSocket.End...() methods) to communicate asynchronously with that client.
Something like this:
program SocketServer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Net.Socket, System.Types;

procedure SendFinished(const ASyncResult: IAsyncResult);
begin
  //...
end;

procedure ReceiveFinished(const ASyncResult: IAsyncResult);
begin
  var Connection := TSocket(ASyncResult.AsyncContext);
  var s := Connection.EndReceiveString(ASyncResult);
  if s <> '' then
  begin
    WriteLn('Received: ' + s);
    WriteLn('Sent: OK');
    Connection.BeginSend('OK', SendFinished);
  end;
end;

procedure AcceptFinished(const ASyncResult: IAsyncResult);
begin
  var Socket := TSocket(ASyncResult.AsyncContext);
  try
    var Connection := Socket.EndAccept(ASyncResult);
    WriteLn('Listening for data');
    Connection.BeginReceive(ReceiveFinished);
  finally
    Socket.BeginAccept(AcceptFinished);
  end;
end;

begin
  WriteLn('Starting Socket');
  var Socket := TSocket.Create(TSocketType.TCP);
  try
    Socket.Listen('127.0.0.1', '', 9006); //Very important ... second param is service
    try
      Socket.BeginAccept(AcceptFinished);
      // do other work until ready to exit
    except
      On E: Exception do
      begin
        WriteLn('Exception happened:' + E.Message);
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Socket.Free;
  end;
end.


Thanks for your suggested solution Remy, unfortunatelly I am not able to connect multiple times and get the response back. I had the BeginAccept in a loop which I will now change. I added a loop with a sleep where you commented //do other work.  On running and connecting I immediately get a timeout on receiving data.  I'm curious why you need to have Socket.BeginAccept again to call the AcceptFinished again after handing off to ReceiveFinished.

"unfortunatelly I am not able to connect multiple times and get the response back" - What I wrote is off the top of my head, I did not test it, so it may require further effort to get it working, but the concept should be clear. If you want to do things asynchronously, you need to use the Begin/End... methods. "I'm curious why you need to have Socket.BeginAccept again to call the AcceptFinished again after handing off to ReceiveFinished" - because Begin/Accept() performs only 1 connection operation at a time. You have to keep calling it to continue accepting further connections.

Thanks Remy, I will post my final solution then, now that I understand the context of above, thanks for the code!

This is an update of something that I have working now based on the answers submitted, I am still trying to figure out whether I may have memory leaks and whether this is the correct way to work with the sockets. However it is doing what it is supposed to and seems to work cross platform
program SocketServer;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.Net.Socket, System.SysUtils, System.Types;

procedure HandleSocketConnection(const Socket: TSocket);
var
  Disconnected : Boolean;

begin
  WriteLn('Receiving the Socket Connection');

  Disconnected := False;

  while not Disconnected do
  begin
    WriteLn('Waiting for a connection');
    if (Socket <> nil) and (Socket.State = [TSocketState.Connected, TSocketState.Client]) then
    begin
      var Content: TBytes := Socket.Receive();
      if StringOf(Content) <> '' then
      begin
        WriteLn (StringOf(Content));
        if Pos( 'quit', StringOf(Content)) <> 0 then  //If the client sends quit it will disconnect
        begin
          Disconnected := True;
          Socket.Close;
        end;
      end;

      //Supposed to check if there is a socket issue but still working on this, idea is to stop the loop
      try
        var CheckSocket : PFdSet;    //Do I need to free this variable?
        New (CheckSocket);
        CheckSocket^.FdSet.fd_count := 0;
        CheckSocket^.&Set(Socket);

        var SocketError := Socket.Select(CheckSocket,CheckSocket,CheckSocket,100);
        if SocketError in [wrTimeOut, wrError] then
        begin
          Socket.Close;
        end;
      except
        Disconnected := True;
      end;
    end
      else
    begin
      //Socket was nil
      Disconnected := True;
    end;
    Sleep(1000);
  end;
end;

procedure HandleConnection(const ASyncResult: IAsyncResult);
begin
  WriteLn('New Connection');
  var Socket := TSocket(ASyncResult.AsyncContext);
  try
    var Connection := Socket.EndAccept(ASyncResult);
    HandleSocketConnection(Connection);
  finally
    Socket.BeginAccept(HandleConnection, 30000);  //Keep the connection alive  ?
  end;
end;

var
  ServerSocket: TSocket;

begin
  ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutDown := True;
  ServerSocket := TSocket.Create(TSocketType.TCP);

  ServerSocket.Listen('127.0.0.1', '', 9006);
  try
    while True do
    begin
      var Handler := ServerSocket.BeginAccept(HandleConnection, 30000);
      Sleep(1000);
    end;

  finally
    ServerSocket.Free;
  end;
end.

